# PHP-python IPC stops suddenly

Tags: javascript, php, python, network-programming, unix-socket

I've implemented a simple python server that creates a Unix-domain socket and listens for data on it. At first I tested this with a text field that would run the PHP script when pressing "Send". After I got that working, I added some jquery and tried sending the keycode of the key that is currently pressed. This whole system will run on a Raspberry Pi.

While building it on Ubuntu, something would stop working:

- if more than about 5 seconds passed with nothing being sent (both with the text field, and with the JavaScript added)
- after a seemingly arbitrary number of sent packets (most of the time at around 101, but sometimes at 30-something, sometimes at 50-ish; I wasn't able to discern any apparent pattern behind this)

Transferring everything onto the Raspberry Pi:

- only every second (every third, after adding the counter) packet would be actually received by the python server
- after about 400 packets received, it starts receives every one, as you send them
- but it no longer stops working completely after a number of sent packets, or after waiting some time without input; it just seems to hang a bit every now and then

At no time does PHP or python give any indication that something is wrong with the socket - I initially debugged the PHP bit with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Python server code:

```
import socket, os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    os.remove("/tmp/socketname")
except OSError:
    print 'OSError'
s.bind("/tmp/socketname")
s.listen(1)
n=0
conn = s.accept()[0]
while 1:
    if not conn:
        break
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
        print '---'
    if data:
        n=n+1
        print n,
        print data
print 'done'
conn.close()
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$sock = pfsockopen  ('unix:///tmp/socketname', 0);

$cmd=$_POST["pressed"];

if(isset($cmd))
{
    if(!$sock) echo("no socket");
    if(!fwrite($sock, $cmd)) echo("Error while writing1!!!<br>\n");
}
?>
```

Relevant parts of the HTML file:

```
<script>     
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
       var req=$.ajax({
          url: "testajaxpost.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: { 'pressed': event.keyCode },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
             {
               alert( "Request failed: " + errorThrown );
             }
                    })
                                   });
</script>
```

It is acting exceedingly strange, and I can't see what might be wrong. I have next to no experience with web programming, so there might be some huge, glaring mistake that I missed.